# KSH : I can't get the value of the parameters from another script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ksh

i'm new in unix and shell script
so the problem is in the WHILE CASE part,
i am running the script something like this

```
 . SCRIPT1 123
```

here's the script1

```
while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do 
ParamLine="$ParamLine $1"
shift
done

$DIR/SCRIPT2$ParamLine  
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
   exit 1
fi
```

and here's the SCRIPT2 that will catch the parameter from SCRIPT1

```
from_prg=genresourceshortage
to_prg=genresourceshortage
batchdate=$BOM_BATCH_DATE


echo "THIS IS THE FIRST PARAMETER "$1


while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
case $1 in
     from=*) from_prg=`echo $1 | cut -c6-`    ;;
       to=*) to_prg=`echo $1 | cut -c4-`      ;;
       oc=*) to_prg=`echo $1 | cut -c4-`      ;;
        -d*) shift
             batchdate=$1                     ;;
          *) echo "<<<<< Invalid restart parameter >>>>>"
             echo "<<<<<        Job Abandoned      >>>>>"
             exit 1                           ;;
esac
   shift
done
#THE CODE IS NOT REACHING THIS PART 
rj $DIR/SCRIPT3from=$from_prg to=$to_prg -d $batchdate
```

how can i get the value from the parameter that i passed from SCRIPT1 to SCRIPT2? because I will use it in my SCRIPT3 also.

It display the default case, this part

```
echo "<<<<< Invalid restart parameter >>>>>"
echo "<<<<<        Job Abandoned      >>>>>"
```

Comment: This `$DIR/SCRIPT2$ParamLine` should be `"$DIR/SCRIPT2" "$ParamLine"`, but the best answer is chepner's

Answer (score 1):

The first script can be replaced with a single line

```
"$DIR"/SCRIPT2 "$@"
```

Trying to condense the arguments to a single flat string is wrong.

Comment: It's working with,  . SCRIPT1 var=1234. how can enter just the value and not with variable?